# Serialize data in react to submit post request

Tags: reactjs

I have a comment form that takes some text input and sends a POST request via AJAX to create a new comment.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
    .
    .
 }}}
render() {

const { data, currentPage, itemsPerPage } = this.state;
const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage;
const currentItems = data.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);
const renderTour = currentItems.map((item, i) => {
    return <form action='' onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e, item, i)} method="post">
        .......
</form>
})}

handleSubmit = (e, element, val) => {
e.preventDefault();
var productid = element.id
if (typeof productid === 'string') {
    var return_Edit = function () {
        var tmp = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'type': "POST",
            'global': false,
            'dataType': 'html',
            'url': "index.bc",
            'data': // ???? - Need to figure out how to serialize data here,
            'success': (response) => {
                tmp = response;
            }
        });
        return tmp;
    }();
}}
```

I need to serialize the form data to send along with my POST request, but I'm not sure how. I know in JQuery I can select the form element and do something like `$("#my_form").serialize()`, but I can't seem to call that from inside the React component.
Is there a way to approach this and will let me serialize my form data within ReactJS?

Comment: `e.target` is your form. You could do `$(e.target).serialize()` or a better option use  native DOM [ways to access field values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements). Also  `'async': false,` is terrible idea.

Comment: Thanks @Yury Tarabanko.It works but why  is  'async': false, terrible idea?

Comment: [Deprecation notice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request) Mainly because using sync requests blocks ui thread leading to very poor UX. UI just "hangs" on slow networks.